# How to xcom_pull a return_value from airflow and pass as dictionary?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a json config file that lists potential tasks to run. From this config file, I want to create a new config that contains only those tasks with a run_date that matches the execution date of my DAG. From there, I want the DAG to evaluate whether it needs to run anything at all, and if so, specifically what it needs to run.

My config looks like:

```
config = {
    "task_1": {
        "run_date": "2021-05-01",
        "other_key": "other_value"
        },
    "task_2": {
        "run_date": "2021-05-02",
        "other_key": "other_value"
        }
    }
```

My dag imports the above config file, and looks like:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test',
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval='0 16 * * *'
)

tasks_to_run = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='tasks_to_run',
    python_callable=tasks_to_run,
    op_kwargs={'config': config, 'execution_date': "{{ ds }}"},
    dag=dag
)

new_config = PythonOperator(
    task_id='new_config',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=new_config,
    op_kwargs={'config': config, 'execution_date': "{{ ds }}"},
    dag=dag
)

next_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='next_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=next_task,
    op_kwargs={'tasks': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='test', task_ids='new_config', key='return_value') }}"}
)
```

'new_config' generates the new config file, and 'next_task' tries to pull in the xcom value. When next_task passes the xcom return_value into the python_callable 'next_task', it fails with:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

How do I pass the xcom return_value into the python callable 'next_task' as a dictionary? As that is what it expects.

Comment: Can you include the snippet for the `next_task` function?  You should be able to pass a dictionary XCom no problem.